# Access Application.Current in .Net Standard Project Library

Tags: xamarin, class-library

My main Xamarin.Forms project has a dependency to a .Net Standard Class Library called Service.
One of the classes is the LoginService which contains the business project for the login. I need to access Application.Current, however, the project library cannot seem to find it.

This is my code iniside one of the functions:

```cs
Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("username")
```

How do I add a reference to Application.Current in a class library in Xamarin?

Comment: the library needs to reference Xamarin.Forms

Comment: So I will just add the Xamarin.Forms NuGet package to the class Library?

Comment: Also thanks for the fast response and help!

Comment: Did you get success after add the Xamarin.Forms NuGet package to the class Library. [application.current](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.application.current?view=xamarin-forms) is a property of Xamarin.forms.

Comment: Yep, it worked!! Thanks

Comment: I add an answer and can you please mark it so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 0):

To access [Application.Current](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.application.current?view=xamarin-forms) in .Net Standard Project Library, you need to reference [Xamarin.Forms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms/).

Class [Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.application?view=xamarin-forms) is under namespace Xamarin.forms.